# Magento 1 - Error messages aren't displaying on checkout

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, checkout

If I drill into the developer toolbar > network, I see there is a /saveAll XHR request which for example has this message inside:

```
billing:
  {error: -1,…}
   error: -1
   message:
   "Email" is not a valid hostname., 'a.cpm' appears to be a DNS 
    hostname but cannot match TLD against known list, 'a.cpm' 
    appears to be a local network name but local network names are not allowed
```

But there is no error message/ alert being displayed on the front end so the user will have no idea what is wrong. Does anyone know what piece of code usually handles these and displays them on the front end so I can see if they have been removed?

I can see where these error messages are originally coming from:

```
OnepageCheckout/controllers/OnepageController.php
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Something is wrong with your checkout js. If you check your console browser console for errors, is there any?

Comment: There's actually no errors in the console, the only errors I can find is the above when digging into the network requests :(

Comment: If I understood correctly you are receiving 500 on some of the errors? You should enable `display_errors` in php.ini (or comment it out in Magento's index.php), that will allow you to actually see the error.